# c# Parse JSON with no reference class?

Tags: c#, json, parsing

I have a JSON similar to the following:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "totalFeatures": "unknown",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "id": "xxx",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPolygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        570389.865,
                        4722149.567
                    ],
                    [
                        570389.865,
                        4722149.567
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a way to get the `coordinates` property of the first `feature` without using `substring` or parsing it to an class that represents that JSON?

I'm looking for something standard for handling JSON strings as an Object, with methods for getting childs by name or similar.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: you can use [JObject](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm)

Comment: I don't think it is possible without any application of sub string or parsing

Comment: @styx, JObject need parsing to work with payload.

Comment: @Nair he said without parsing into representative class, not without parsing at all

Comment: @styx, If I read it correct, 'parsing it to a class that represents that JSON'. JObject.Parse initialize a new instance of the JObject class for the given json representation / data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) library.

Here's example of getting `coordinates` field (using JSONPath):

```
var parsed = JObject.Parse(yourJson);

// returns JToken (but actually it's JArray, derived from JToken)
var coordArrayToken = parsed.SelectToken("$.features[0].geometry.coordinates");
var coordinates = coordArrayToken.ToObject<decimal[][]>();
```

Of course you can use simple indexers:

```
var parsed = JObject.Parse(yourJson);

// returns JToken (but actually it's JArray, derived from JToken)
var coordArrayToken = parsed["features"].Children().First()["geometry"]["coordinates"];
var coordinates = coordArrayToken.ToObject<decimal[][]>();
```